# Do Shojo and Bishonen overlap, or are they separate?

Tags: terminology

I was checking out the new season of anime and came across a self-described shojo [anime](https://myanimelist.net/anime/36649/Banana_Fish), but judging by the cover art, name, and description, I assumed a Bishonen anime.  As I was making a joke to a friend, I realized that shojo and bishonen weren't the exact same thing.  Somehow I had conflated the two.

Are the two terms overlapping genres, or is one a genre and the other a subgenre?  I'm not sure where one ends and the other begins.

Answer (score 4):

Shoujo is a genre of manga/anime targeted at girls. [There's an explanation here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/what-are-the-differences-between-types-of-anime/2341#2341) that covers it, but basically, it's manga/anime where the target demographic is 8-17-year-old girls.

Bishonen is an aesthetic/style that refers to pretty boys, who generally have feminine and delicate features. It most often shows up in shoujo and yaoi manga/anime, but it isn't exclusive to them. An entire manga/anime can be drawn in the bishonen style or individuals can be. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bish%C5%8Dnen))